# Unable to create custom template with custom name (-n) - dotnet new

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

### **Unable to create a custom template with a custom name (-n) - dotnet new**

When I run the below command, it's creating a Solution - by name Test.sln

**dotnet new sln -n Test.sln**

here **sln** is the default template.

Whereas, if I run the below command to create - *custom template* with some other name, it's still extracting the template under *default name*.

**dotnet new MessageHandler -n TestHandler**

Expected *MessageHandler* to be created/extracted is - **TestHandler.cs**

Whereas, its extracting/creating under the deafult name - **MessageHandler.cs**

PS,

I am following the below link to create Custom Template.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/create-custom-template

request to Stackoverflow community - kindly create a tag - dotnet-new

Answer (score 0):

add sourceName to your .template.json file , llike this:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
"author": "phiree",
......
"shortName": "TestHandler",
"sourceName":"TestHandler"  <-----------this is the key
}
```

the -n|--name will replace the "sourceName",references to :

https://reynders.co/create-your-own-templates-for-dotnet-new/